# How to filter a webpage and get the required data using android

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am designing an Android application which will shows the details of nearby coffee shops...i need to get this content from google.I am searching in google by "COFFEE NEAR LOCATION", this location determined by the application itself.I know how to take source code of that web site and take the content which i need but its taking too much time to process and the source code of that page(google source code) is too big..So is there any alternative way to do this thing..to get this particular content from google..Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to scrape google..

Comment: Are you using google custom search api?

Comment: No i am not using any custom search api

Comment: The searching should be done in background and only the content should get to my app

Comment: Wait, which country are you looking at?

Comment: country :India but the location is determined by the app itself and the searching is done with the current location where they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the [Google-Places-API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). It allows you to query for places near your location and get all information like you would get if you use the google serach. It is easy to use. If you want to search for any location you need to do an HTTP request which would look like this one

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

An examples query would look like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

and the response in a json or an XML which only contains the information you ask for. Parameters are `location`,`radius`,`keyword`,`language`,`opennow`,`type` and many more. But suggest you visit the link, it helps you getting started. The API key is for free unless you have a lot of traffic (thousands of requests per day)

Comment: How to use this Google-Place API

Comment: But am not able to get the phone number. 
The json file which returned by google place api doesn't containing the phone number

Answer (score 1):

Using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) it's easy and fast. You can use the following method to query Google and fetch the resulting links.

```
public static final String URL_FORMAT = "http://www.google.com/search?&q=%s&num=%d";
public static final String LINK_SELECTOR = "div.g>h3>a";
public static final Pattern GOOGLE_RESULTS_URL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^.*q=(.*?)&.*$");

public static List<Link> search(String phrase, int number){
    List<Link> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String url;
    Elements links;

    // Build and encode url for Google search
    try {
        url = String.format(URL_FORMAT, URLEncoder.encode(phrase, Constants.CHARSET), number);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    // Connect to Google and fetch the results
    try {
        links = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT)
                .timeout(Constants.FETCH_TIMEOUT)
                .get()
                .select(LINK_SELECTOR);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    // Iterate through links and add them to the list
    for (Element link : links) {
        String title = link.text();
        url = link.absUrl("href");
        Matcher matcher = GOOGLE_RESULTS_URL_PATTERN.matcher(url);

        if(matcher.matches()) {
            try {
                url = URLDecoder.decode(matcher.group(1), Constants.CHARSET);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
        results.add(new Link(title, url));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Also here is a good [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/) for getting started with jsoup.

Comment: Actually i need name ,location and phone number of each shops..is it possible to get using this code.

Comment: @SushinPv No, this code only returns URLs found by Google for a query phrase. You should open them one by one and fetch the required data.